# Scrapy xpath how to

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

My spider needs to be somewhat adaptable for the site I am scraping in that the info I need to fetch is at times in div[1] and at other times in div[2]. Here's an example:

```
item['details'] = site.select('//*[@id="detailFacts"]/div[2]/div[2]//text()').extract()
```

or

```
item['details'] = site.select('//*[@id="detailFacts"]/div[1]/div[2]//text()').extract()
```

How do I combine both of these in a single statement so that scrapy fetches me from EITHER of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
details = site.select('//*[@id="detailFacts"]/div[1]/div[2]//text()|//*[@id="detailFacts"]/div[2]/div[2]//text()').extract()
item['details'] = next(s for s in details if s)  # getting first not-empty item from the list
```

or

```
details = site.select('//*[@id="detailFacts"]/div[1]|div[2]/div[2]//text()').extract()
item['details'] = next(s for s in details if s)  # getting first not-empty item from the list
```

Hope it works for you.